# Reload Datatables without hidden bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Checking Datatables docs I'm using child rows and data from mysql database. Each child rows has modals with ID of each data row as part of ID name.

I want to reload datatable so I use this line code:

```
$('#mytable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

It works correctly but the problem is when I open a modal, modal hides when datatable reloads. How can I avoid this?

Comment: so you want to persist the modal even after datatable loads?

Comment: You could try moving any open modals to a different parent such as body before reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your callback and after your ajax call.   Maybe before it too.

```
  If ($('#modal').not('.visible')) {

        $('#modal').show();

   }
```

If that doesn't work maybe set_interval in recursive loop etc..